# Android Emulator - Blue tint when switching monitors

Tags: android, emulation

Every time I move an emulator window from one monitor to another, the emulator turns blue... it gets this weird bluish hue like I've just highlighted it.

Anybody else have this start happening with the latest AVD update?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73017/blue-emulator.png

Comment: Yes, I've been having the same problem.  In fact, my emulator won't even load the home screen when switching it to my other monitor.

Comment: Same thing here.  Any fixes yet?

Comment: I haven't found any solution, no. It seems like there are a lot of emulator problems with multiple monitors in the latest update (such as not being able to restart an emulator if you close it on a 2nd monitor).

Comment: I guess it's a bug. I use a Mac without a second monitor, and this happens. The blue tint is removed, when I hover the cursor over some buttons on the emulated keyboard, and on the main screen, if I switch to different activity, or make the UI redraw in a way, the tint gets removed for that portion which is redrawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are looking into it. Please refer to: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38913

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the info. To quote: A fix has been checked in to the AOSP source and will be in a future SDK tools release.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38913#c9